# Как можно вычислить закрытый квартал в sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица. Нужно посчитать сумму (salary) всех работников за закрытый квартал, если квартал еще не завершен то показывать сумму за предыдущий закрытый квартал,если предыдущий квартал не завершен то показывать 0

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *за закрытый квартал, если квартал еще не завершен* Что имеется в виду под закрытостью и завершённостью квартала? Как определить?

Comment: Например у нас в таблице есть данные на 2019-10-14 - это 4 квартал, но так как посчитать суму зарплат  за этот квартал всех fio  мы не можем так как он не завершенный (нету данных за 11,12 месяц), то мы выводим сумму за предыдущий квартал за который мы можем посчитать сумму, так как у нас имеются данные за полных три месяца, если за предыдущий квартал нету данных и мы не можем его посчитать то сумма будет равна 0 , как в примере за 2019-06-30

Comment: Хреновый признак. Наличие данных за июнь по всем записям не гарантирует, что не появятся ещё записи, например.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если версия SQL Server 2012 или выше, то можно воспользоваться функцией [LAG](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016).

```sql
select
  s.[date], s.fio, s.salary,
  datepart(quarter, s.[date]) quarter_nbr,
  j1.quarter_salary
from salaries s
join (
  select
    a2.prev_quarter, a1.cur_quarter, a2.next_quarter,
    case count(distinct a1.cur_month)
      when 3 then sum(s.salary)
      else case
             when lag(
                    count(distinct a1.cur_month)
                  ) over(order by a1.cur_quarter) = 3 and
                  lag(
                    a1.cur_quarter
                  ) over(order by a1.cur_quarter) = a2.prev_quarter
             then lag(sum(s.salary)) over(order by a1.cur_quarter)
             else 0
           end
    end quarter_salary
  from salaries s cross apply (
    select dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, [date]), 0) cur_quarter,
           dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, [date]), 0) cur_month
  ) a1 cross apply(
    select dateadd(quarter, -1, cur_quarter) prev_quarter,
           dateadd(quarter, 1, cur_quarter) next_quarter
  ) a2
  group by a2.prev_quarter, a1.cur_quarter, a2.next_quarter
) j1
on s.[date] >= j1.cur_quarter and s.[date] < j1.next_quarter;
```

**Вывод:**

```
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------------+
|    date    |   fio   | salary | quarter_nbr | quarter_salary |
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------------+
| 2018-12-31 | Сидоров |   2000 |           4 |           4400 |
| 2018-11-28 | Иванов  |   1200 |           4 |           4400 |
| 2018-10-31 | Иванов  |   1200 |           4 |           4400 |
| 2019-06-30 | Иванов  |   1200 |           2 |              0 |
| 2019-09-30 | Сидоров |   1400 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-09-16 | Иванов  |   1800 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-08-31 | Сидоров |   2000 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-08-31 | Иванов  |   1200 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-07-31 | Сидоров |   2000 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-07-31 | Иванов  |   1200 |           3 |           9600 |
| 2019-10-14 | Сидоров |   2900 |           4 |           9600 |
| 2019-10-14 | Иванов  |   1800 |           4 |           9600 |
+------------+---------+--------+-------------+----------------+
```

Демо на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d32507/4).